# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEFAULT_INCOMPATIBLE_IMPROVEMENTS

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jar, freemarker

Kindly anyone let me know How to solve this error,

I'm using spring-webmvc.3.2.17 and freemarker.2.3.16

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'freemarkerConfig' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEFAULT_INCOMPATIBLE_IMPROVEMENTS
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 51 more
```

Here is my bean

```
<bean id="freemarkerConfig"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
    <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="/" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <property name="freemarkerSettings">
        <props>
            <prop key="date_format">dd MMM yyyy</prop>
            <prop key="datetime_format">yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss</prop>
            <prop key="number_format">########</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: what is your freemarker version?

Comment: Freemarker version is 2.3.16

Comment: seems there is a transitive dependency conflict in your dependencies. can you also update your pom.xml

Comment: Our application not using pom.xml, Instead adding dependencies through .classpath.xml

Comment: Use org.freemarker:freemarker:2.3.20 at least or the latest version. see https://www.versioneye.com/java/org.springframework:spring-webmvc/3.2.17.RELEASE

Comment: Ok, Sorry to ask, But what version of freemarker will compatible with spring-webmv.4.3.0.RELEASE.jar

Comment: for spring-webmv.4.3.0.RELEASE freemarker:2.3.23 is required. see https://www.versioneye.com/java/org.springframework:spring-webmvc/4.3.0.RELEASE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

spring-webmvc.3.2.17 requires **freemarker:2.3.20** or higher.
see https://www.versioneye.com/java/org.springframework:spring-webmvc/3.2.17.RELEASE